# Codeigniter json encoded data retrived using AJAX not accessible in php

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to do a live search in a codeigniter file of which this is the AJAX autocomplete

```
     $(this).ready( function() 
    {
        $("#id").autocomplete
        ({
          minLength: 1,
          source: 
          function(req, add){
              $.ajax({
                  url:'<?php echo site_url('autocomplete/lookup'); ?>',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: req,
                  success:    
                  function(data){
                      if(data.response =="true"){
                          add(data.message); // displays the retrieved data
                        }
                    },

                });
            },     
        });
    });
```

The lookup function of the autocomplete controller is

```
public function lookup(){
    // process posted form data
    //echo $this->input->post('term'); exit;
    $keyword = $this->input->post('term');

    $data['response'] = 'false'; //Set default response
    $query = $this->MAutocomplete->lookup($keyword); //Search DB
    if( ! empty($query) )
    {
        $data['response'] = 'true'; //Set response
        $data['message'] = array(); //Create array
        foreach( $query as $row )
        {
            $data['message'][] = array( 
                                    'id'=>$row->id,
                                    'value' => $row->firstname,

                                 );  //Add a row to array
        }
    }
    if('IS_AJAX')
    {

        echo json_encode($data); //echo json string if ajax request


    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('data_view',$data); //Load html view of search results
    }
}
```

I am able to access the data that is being returned in the json encoded form using the add(data.message) located in the view code.
I am unable to access this data outside the ajax code, what should i do to let me use this returned data in my php code.

Comment: put `console.log(data)` in you success function.dont alert it

Comment: @NishantNair i haven't used alert i have used add which adds the data retrieved to a drop down list

Comment: oh sorry i read it wrongly. what is add method doing? Where is the implementation?

Comment: @NishantNair It is a part of the jquery probably as the add function was apart of the code i read to do this the only explenation provided was that it displayed the data

Comment: have you tried using below answer. You should decode your data before use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also I can see the data is encoded into json. So you need to decode it in js.

```
  success:    
      function(data){
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // if using jquery

         console.log(obj.message); // check your data and the use it accordingly.
      },
```

In you controller

```
$isAJAX     = $this->input->post('isAjax');
if($isAJAX)
{
    echo json_encode($data); //echo json string if ajax request

}
else
{
    $this->load->view('data_view',$data); //Load html view of search results
}
```

Comment: When I used this code in place of the add function i got an error SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: if you are using jquery try `jQuery.parseJSON(data);`

Comment: I already did use this code that is what brought the error i spoke of in the above comment. Is there any other why i can display this obj to check if the   JSON is being parsed

Comment: It seems you code in not entering into the if `$isAJAX  = $this->input->post('isAjax');`  Try $isAjax in if condition

Comment: no need to parse the data if you are using `dataType: 'json'` and the data being returned is actually JSON

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
if('IS_AJAX')
```

I suggest (using the input class)

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

This uses the HEAD details from the form post to determine if the request is an xhrrequest

Answer (score 0):

I managed to Solve my question thanks to finding out that since the data type is JSON I do not need to parse the JSON.

Simply doing

```
obj = data.message;
console.log(obj);
```

[This shows the JSON being displayed in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm7Zq.png)